# ERROR:-->PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

what's the fail on trigger???? I'm trying create a trigger that be activated when a datetime is found
on interval of time.

```
 CREATE TABLE R
 (
  OID_R     NUMBER NOT NULL,
  Price     INTEGER NOT NULL,
  f         DATE    NOT NULL,
  HourStart DATE    NOT NULL,
  HuorFin   DATE    NOT NULL,
  OID_E     NUMBER          ,
  OID_S     NUMBER          ,
  OID_P     NUMBER NOT NULL
 );

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_D
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF OID_R ON R
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  IntervalR DATE;
  HourStart DATE;
  HourFin   DATE;
BEGIN
  IntervalR := :new.HourFin - :new.HourStart;
  IF IntervalR BETWEEN :old.HourStart AND :old.HourFin THEN
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Is not avaible');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: A `date` minus a `date` isn't a date but the number of days. So `IntervalR := :NEW.HourFin - :NEW.HourStart;` cannot work because `IntervalR` is a `date`. Unfortunately you didn't give a useful description of what you want to do. So I cannot give any advice on how to change it to achieve what you want.

Comment: The trigger must be activated when the `IntervalR` is between Date `HourStart` and Date `HourFin`. Maybe I should try to find a function that return the difference of dates not like a int, but that saves the time interval between these two dates.

Comment: That doensn't make sense to me. Maybe you're after `:new.hourstart >= :old.hourstart
AND :new.hourfin <= :old.hourfin`. But who knows. A [example] could help.

Comment: @MJJS1996 a date is not an interval. Can you explain the business rule you want to enforce? `HourFin` must be after `HourStart`, something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Your description says "when a datetime is found on interval of time" then you test if the difference between the new values falls between the old values. This will never work, but it appears the actual problem you are trying to solve is "determine if the new times overlap the old ones or can the times be reset".  
Your trigger has some fundamental flaws beyond the misunderstanding of result of subtracting one date from another.  Your trigger fires on insert but then uses a column from the old row, but on insert there is no old row so all operations with it result in NULL. Therefore your IF statement can never be true. So no need to fire on insert. The trigger also fires on update, but not any update. Only when the column OID_R is updated, If OID_R is not a column in the set list the trigger does not fire on update. It also appears the OID_R is (or at least should be) the primary key in which it should **never** be updated during normal operations. So should never fire on update. You define three variables, one incorrectly and the other two not used, so none of then are needed. We are left with the original question *do the new times overlap the old ones*?  
Lets define valid resets as when:

1. new end is greater than new start
2. current time is less than new start
3. current time is less than old start

With that we get (note there may be other conditions)

```
create or replace trigger tr_d
  before  update on r
  for each row
begin
   if not (    new.endhour > :new.starthour  
           and sysdate     < :new.starthour
           and sysdate     < :old.starthour
          )
   then 
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'is not avaible');
  end if;
end tr_d;
```

The outstanding question is "do the times represent values repeating daily (ie times only) or indicate times on a specific date? If repeats daily then you need to strip the day, month, year from values and sysdate.